# Get columns from two tables sql

Tags: sql

I need some help on doing query to get one column from one table and another column from another table.

```
Table 1
Id     column1         
===    =======
1      text1
2      text2
3      text3 
Table 2
Id     column2   table1.Id
===    =======   =========
1      text1      2
2      text2      3
```

I need the result to be

```
table1.Id    table1.column1   table2.column2
=========    ==============   ==============
   1           text1             null
   2           text2             text2
   3           text3             text3
```

I need column 1 from table1 and column2 from table 2 based on table1. I need to get the column2 value for the records in table1. Can anyone help me on this?.

I have tried

```
SELECT table1.column1 , table2.column2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Id = table2.table1.Id
ORDER BY table.Id;
```

I need all the records from table1 but with the above query I am getting more number of records.

For some reason i am getting more records than expected, I have 10 records in table1, I should get only 10 and their corresponding column 2 value but I am getting more records. I want same records table 1 contains as result

Comment: check my answer and queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my bad english, if you want records which match primary and foriegn key you should use `INNER JOIN` query like this

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM tab1 t1 INNER JOIN tab2 t2
ON (t1.id = t2.tab1Id) ORDER BY t1.id
```

But if you want all records which match primary and foriegn key or match not so you should use `LEFT JOIN` query like this

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM tab1 t1 LEFT JOIN tab2 t2
ON (t1.id = t2.tab1Id) ORDER BY t1.id
```

Comment: For some reason i am getting more records than expected, I have 10 records in table1, I should get only 10 but I am getting more records. I want same records in table1

Comment: Are you using `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` query... And also in table1 you've 10 records, and in table2 how many records do you have and also foreign key...

Comment: I have tried both, but in the results I am getting more number of records. Table1 should have upper hand and if there is no value in column2 i should get null. In Table2 I have only 4 records.

Comment: Use this `ON (t1.id = t2.tab1Id)` instead of `ON table1.Id = table2.table1.Id`...

Comment: Tried but there is no change, I have updated my question with the result that i needed. please check it once. Thank you very much for helping me on this.

Comment: It worked, but I guess I have duplicates on table2 which is the cause to return more number of records

Comment: check my updated `LEFT JOIN` query it will return you your desired result... If you see your table1 and table2, In table1 at id 2 you've record `text2` and at id 1 and foreign key you've 2 in table2, so join always match numeric keys not character records...

Comment: I need one more help on this, I am getting multiple records but I just need one more condition, Can i get the records based on the column2 in table2.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet

```
SELECT table1.column1 , table2.column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.Id = table2.table1.Id 
--ON table1.Id = table2.[table1.Id] -- Also try with this
ORDER BY table1.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT table1.column1 , table2.column2
 FROM table1
 LEFT JOIN table2
 ON table1.Id = table2.table1.Id
 ORDER BY table1.Id ASC;
```